# Getting System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception when try to run an application written in F#

Tags: f#

Please keep in mind that I am new to world of .Net and F#. I apologize in advance if my question sounds stupid or I don’t use the correct terminology. Having said that, here is my question:

I wrote a simple F# consol application using visual studio 2010. After successfully executes the application on my computer, I moved the executable file found under debug directory to different computer and try to execute it. This results in the following execption

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at .$Program.main@()

The tagger machine has .net 4 installed. I checked the GAC and found the following “FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”

But application is looking for FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0. If I understood correctly, there is no such version of F# 4.0 is available, so why my application is looking for Version=4.0.0.0? Any help is welcome

Thanks

Sudaly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the other machine have the [F# Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5f0a79f8-925f-4297-9ae2-86e2fdcff33c) installed on it?

Comment: No, i didn’t have the runtime installed. i installed the "Standalone compiler and tools" found under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/fsharp/cc835251.aspx and .Net 4. i was under the impression that all it need to run the application. Now that i have installed the runtime my application works. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: In most cases all you need to run an F# app is the runtime, and not the compiler and tools. There's also a compiler option to embed the runtime inside your executable - increases the side of your program, but nothing other than the correct version of .NET is required on the target machine.

Comment: @sudaly, for info, the option that Joel refers to is `--standalone` (or was, the last time I tried it)